# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "manager_name" of recursive query "manager"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I always get the error

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "manager_name" of recursive query "manager".

on the following query, even when CASTing all columns, what am I doing wrong?

```
WITH manager (
    full_name,
    first_name,
    email,
    crm_user_id,
    "role",
    parent_role,
    manager_name,
    manager_email,
    crm_manager_id,
    role_path,
    manager_path
)
AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(full_name as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(first_name as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(email as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(crm_user_id as VARCHAR(18)),
        CAST([role] as VARCHAR(128)),
        CAST(parent_role as VARCHAR(128)),
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(18)),
        CAST([role] as VARCHAR(max)),
        CAST(full_name as VARCHAR(max))
    FROM dbo.Forecast_owners
    WHERE parent_role IS NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(employee.full_name as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(employee.first_name as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(employee.email as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(employee.crm_user_id as VARCHAR(18)),
        CAST(employee.[role] as VARCHAR(128)),
        CAST(employee.parent_role as VARCHAR(128)),
        CAST(manager.full_name as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(manager.email as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(manager.crm_user_id as VARCHAR(18)),
        CAST((manager.role_path + '/' + employee.[role]) as VARCHAR(max)),
        CAST((manager.manager_path + '/' + employee.full_name) as VARCHAR(max))
    FROM
        dbo.Forecast_owners employee
    JOIN manager ON employee.parent_role = manager.[role]
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    manager
```

Table DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Forecast_owners (
    full_name varchar(512) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    first_name varchar(512) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    email varchar(512) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    crm_user_id varchar(18) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [role] varchar(128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    parent_role varchar(128) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
);
```

Running

`SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));`

I get the Server Collation to be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: Create a DBFiddle that shows the issue.

Comment: Remember these values will be additive after each recursion. Try switching to MAX lengths

Comment: I'm betting you didn't save the proc.

Comment: I would have expected that to work, so I'm wondering if there's something weird going on with collations. Could you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74556249/edit) your question to include the DDL of the `dbo.Forecast_owners` table along with the database's and tempdb's default collation settings?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning added table DDL

Comment: @PatrickHurst tried with varchar(max) everywhere and got the same result

Comment: @DaleK i found no support for MS SQL Server on DBFiddle.

Comment: And your database default collations? Those `CAST(NULL AS ...)` expressions will probably be using your database's default collation, e.g.: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS `, instead of the matching column's collation, `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Comment: @PedroPaixao https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly your database's default collation does not match the collation specified on these three columns:

```sql
    first_name varchar(512) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    email varchar(512) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    crm_user_id varchar(18) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
```

In the anchor part of your statement you could replace this part:

```sql
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(18)),
```

With this:

```sql
        CAST(NULL + '' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL + '' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as VARCHAR(512)),
        CAST(NULL + '' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as VARCHAR(18)),
```

And I would expect your error to be corrected.

Comment: Nice catch! We're always learning.....